# Log in with password not working(Lubuntu-15.04)

Tags: login, password, login-screen

I have enabled the Password:asked on login from the users and groups available in the system tools. But however it's not working for me.
When I login to lubuntu it automatically goes to the session without prompting for the password.
I have also tried the nopasswdlogin command but it's not helping.
The login screen doesn't appear too.
I have Dell vostro n series lap.Is it a bug or something else? 
I am a new user to ubuntu so I don't know what to do.
Anyone please help me to fix this problem.